# MATLAB - Intersect between a surface and a plane

Tags: matlab, modeling, intersection

I have a 3D mesh like in this picture.

[image]

Now what I want to do is create a plane that will intersect the surface at a certain Z value. I would then want to get the x and y coordinates of this intersection and have matlab output them.

What I'm planning on doing is that this picture is a model of a lake. This lake will have water evaporating that will be removing a certain z value of water. I would then like to see what the new shoreline would look like by obtaining the x and y coordinates of this intersection.

This is my code for plotting that picture.

```
function plot(x,y,z)
Contour = xlsread('C:\Users\Joel\Copy\Contour','A2:D4757');
x = Contour(:,1);
y = Contour(:, 2);
z = Contour(:,3);
F = TriScatteredInterp(x,y,z);
[X,Y]=meshgrid(linspace(-600,600,300));
Z=F(X,Y);
surf(X,Y,Z);
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by simply thresholding the interpolated `Z` values

```
inside = Z < seaLevel; % binary mask of points inside water
shoreline = bwmorph( inside, 'remove' ); % a mask with only shoreline pixels eq to 1
figure;
surf( X, Y, Z, 'EdgeColor', 'none', 'FaceColor', [210,180,140]/255, 'FaceAlpha', .5 );
hold on;
ii = find( shoreline );
plot3( X(ii), Y(ii), seaLevel*ones(size(ii)), 'b', 'LineWidth', 2 );
```

Comment: Wow. I didn't know you could create a mask of the surface.               surf( X, Y, Z, 'EdgeColor', 'none', 'FaceColor', [210,180,140]/255, 'FaceAlpha', .5 ); what exactly is going on in that line of code past the XYZ?

Comment: @JoelSanchez have you tried this? I basically added some surface parameters to improve the surface plot.

Comment: Yes I did. I like it. It's very neat. Also, Is there a place that has the actual documentation of the functions /classes we are using. Like when I look up polyarea it tells me how to use it but is there a place that shows what is coding behind that function?

Comment: You can always look in mathworks website. For example here's a documentation of [`surf` properties](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/surface_props.html). you can also see this doc in Matlab by typing `>> doc surf`. For some functions you can actually see thier code, just type `>> edit bwmorph`

Answer (score 1):

The contour3 will give nicer boundaries:

```
[h,c]=contour3(X,Y,Z,[seaLevel seaLevel]);
```

seaLevel is given twice: otherwise contour3 thinks seaLevel is the number of levels to automatically calibrate. And to nicely annotate with the numeric height of your seaLevel:

```
clabel(h,c);
```

you may modify c to print "sea level" instead of num2str(seaLevel).

Comment: I'm relatively new to MATLAB coding so what exactly are h and c? Do I have to declare them anywhere? Or are h and c the values of x and y at that specific seaLevel value? Let's say for instance -246?

Comment: Ah ok. Still trying to get used to Matlab coming from C++ and Java. Is there a way that I could fill in the enclosed contour? Shade it in a specific color?

Comment: set(hsurf,'FaceColor','interp'); with hsurf computed by hsurf=surf(X,Y,Z) ? fill3 ? Please read their documentations. And this is not in your initial question, please edit it.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have the MATLAB toolbox for image processing you can't use the function "bwmorph". As a solution you can replace line 2 of Shai's code with the following code which reimplements the bwmorph function for parameter 'remove'. (The reimplementation is probably neither very perfomrant nor an exact reimplementatin (the borders of the matrix aren't used) - but the solution should work as a first step. Feel free to improve).

```
shoreline= zeros(size(inside));

for i_row = 2:size(inside,1)-1
    for i_col = 2:size(inside,2)-1
        if(inside(i_row,i_col))
            if (~(  inside(i_row+1,i_col) && ...
                    inside(i_row-1,i_col) && ...
                    inside(i_row,i_col+1) && ...
                    inside(i_row,i_col-1)))
                inside2(i_row,i_col) = 1;
            end
        end
    end
end
```